# Combining Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

I am using Attributes in a serializable properties object that is used to read/write xml config file for my app and display using Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid. I use c# Attributes to achieve this and would like to be able to combine values of attributes so that my `[Description]` includes `[DefaultSettingValueAttribute]`.

For example, here is how one property is defined:

```
`[Category("General")]
[Description("Default Filename")]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("sample.txt")]
public string DefaultFileName { get; set; } = "sample.txt";`
```

What I would like to be able to do is something on the lines of:

```
`[Category("General")]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("sample.txt")]

[Description("Default Filename: " + 
global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute]

public string DefaultFileName { get; set; } = "sample.txt";`
```

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this?

Comment: This isn't very clear. If your `Description` attribute contains a string, it can contain any string you want. But it looks like you're trying to append an attribute to a string.

Comment: You are correct - I am trying to append an attribute to the string (which in turn is a value for another attribute).
I am trying to avoid to manually copy "sample.txt" between different attributes, I want to define once "DefaultValue" and then reuse that value in other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

At the very minimum, if two strings have different meaning then I wouldn't combine them. If you combine them then what you have is one big string, and whatever part of your code looks at that string has to know how to parse it back into its original pieces.

You can just as easily create an attribute that contains two strings. For example,

```
public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomeAttribute() { }

    public SomeAttribute(string category, string description)
    {
        Category = category;
        Description = description;
    }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

No need to combine them.

But another question is, are the values related somehow so that they actually belong in the same attribute? I don't know how your attribute is used. But unless they're intrinsically related, it may be better to even keep them as separate attributes. If there's a logical distinction between two strings, use two strings, and the same for attributes.

Or perhaps what you might want is for one attribute to inherit from the other:

```
public class BaseAttribute : Attribute
{
    public BaseAttribute() { }

    public BaseAttribute(string defaultValue = null)
    {
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
}

public class SomeAttribute : BaseAttribute
{
    public SomeAttribute() { }

    public SomeAttribute(string category, string description, string defaultValue = null)
        :base(defaultValue)
    {
        Category = category;
        Description = description;
    }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now the second attribute contains its own properties plus that of the base attribute.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Perhaps I should have been clearer at the start - the reason I was avoiding custom attributes as ultimately I "feed" them into the Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid to display/edit properties. I have tried using custom attributes but I can't get PropertyGrid to recognise my custom attribute and display things such as description correctly. So unless you can point me to how can I get PropertyGrid to use my own attributes instead of base classes this won't work in my scenario.